# Combine 2 queries using the window function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to merge these two queries using a window function. I know I need an over partition by then, but I'm not sure how to use this function. I have calculated the average value and average points of soccer clubs now I want to put them next to each other to be able to make a ggplot.

```
select 
    f.ClubName, 
    sum(w.waarde) * 100.0 / sum(sum(w.waarde)) over()
from 
    fact f
join 
    waarde w on w.WDID = f.WDID
group by 
    f.clubname
```

```
select 
    f.ClubName, 
    sum(u.p) * 100.0 / sum(sum(u.p)) over()
from 
    fact f
join 
    uitslag u on u.StandID = f.StandID
group by 
    f.clubname
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining all 3 tables would create duplicate rows and probably would return wrong results, so I suggest a simple join of these 2 queries:

```
select f1.ClubName, f1.avgpoints, f2.avgvalue
from (
  select f.ClubName, sum(w.waarde) * 100.0 / sum(sum(w.waarde)) over() avgpoints
  From fact f join waarde w
  on w.WDID = f.WDID
  group by f.clubname 
) f1 inner join (
  select f.ClubName, sum(u.p) * 100.0 / sum(sum(u.p)) over() avgvalue
  From fact f join uitslag u
  on u.StandID = f.StandID
  group by f.clubname 
) f2 on f2.ClubName = f1.ClubName
```

This will work if both joined queries return the same `ClubName`s.
If a `ClubName` maybe missing form one of the queries then a `full join` would do.